# Name of an enclosure in the shape of a DIP

Tags: identification, packages, dip

Years ago, in a junk bin far away, I saw a device which was a small plastic box with protruding pins in the form of a 14-pin DIP — so that you could solder jumpers or small axial components to the inside end of the pins, close it up, and have a module of your own design that could be plugged into a DIP socket.

**What would these be (or have been) called?**

I have a use for one, if I can find it. (Of course, I could abuse a DIP socket by soldering or just pushing individual leads into it, but in my experience, sockets have shorter (or thicker) leads and a shape not best suited for plugging *into* a socket, and it would be an open frame rather than enclosed. If that's my only option, I'll take it, but I'd like to evaluate the alternative I once saw.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"DIP header". For example, [this](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/56799.pdf?_ga=2.182444259.552657555.1534629132-195534302.1534290494) one.

[image]

Some may have covers available. Eg. [Aries](https://www.arieselec.com/products/data/12033-header-covers.pdf). They're a niche product, so not cheap.

Comment: Thank you! That looks almost exactly like the style I remembered!

Answer (score 2):

[DIP+component+header](https://www.google.ie/search?q=dip+component+header) works for me.

[image]

*Figure 1. No lids but nice solder terminals.*

Comment: Be gentle with the soldering, to avoid melting the plastic header.

Comment: [Matching covers are available too.](https://www.digikey.com/catalog/en/partgroup/650-series-aries-electronics/7869)